# Are image maps (html tag - <map>) crawled by google?

Tags: html, image, dictionary, imagemap, google-crawlers

Does anyone know with any degree of certainty if image maps are crawled by google?

I want to implement an image bar - that has 10 logos of our partners on, and use imagemap to link to their websites. Would google's spider be able to crawl it?

```
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Partners" usemap="#partnermap" />

<map name="partnermap">
  <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="http://partner1.com" alt="Partner1" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="http://partner2.com" alt="Partner2" />
  <area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="http://partner3.com" alt="Partner3" />
 etc ....
</map>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been wondering this recently too and found this within the Google developer instructions around enterprise site search - https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/68/admin_crawl/Introduction#areatag

This suggests that the Google Search Appliance crawler will not follow these links. Whether that is also true for regular Googlebot I don't know but it would seem likely...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but they are treated as graphical links and are not as important. If you include alt text and title text, I think it will be ranked a little higher.

Comment: Thank you. So am I better of creating 10 images with 10 links or an imagemap? ( using alt and title - goes without saying) .

Comment: Also do you have a reference to google's guidelines on this subject by any chance? I can't find anything - just links to Google Maps

Comment: An imagemap should work just as well as 10 images with 10 links.

Comment: @PeterOlson What source leads you to say that imagemaps work as well as separate image links?